# value in array that occurs odd number of times- what is happening here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I came across this code when I checked how to find the number that occurs odd number of times.
I tried to understand everything but I ca figure this out.
Please tell what is happening step by step and what each variable means.

Thank you!

```
function findOdd(A) {
    let counts = A.reduce((p, n) => (p[n] = ++p[n] || 1, p), {});
    return +Object.keys(counts).find(k => counts[k] % 2) || undefined;
```

Comment: Do you understand all the functions SEPARATELY? Like what does reduce() do? Find? And so on?

Comment: Here is an alternative less cryptic way of writing the function, extracting logic into separate functions. Resulting in a more readable `findOdd` function. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/c40318ba4c0b05c570fdcc9b9f99ed0c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is an Array method which should reduce an array to a single value, which could be an array itself, an object or any flat variable type
- `reduce` will take a function and an initial accumulating object as parameters
- The function is called for each element in the array and be passed the accumulating object as first parameter (p) and the single array item as second parameter (n)
- The function is in this case an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- The function body consists of two expressions connected by the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). The comma operator will return the rightmost expression as a result, in this case `p`.
- The first expression of the comma operator (`p[n] = ++p[n] || 1`) will return `1` if `p[n]` is not set, otherwise will increment `p[n]` and return the result. Thanks to the [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation) of the logical OR (`||`)
- This could be written a little bit more detailed as

```
A.reduce(function (p, n) {
  if (p[n]) {
    p[n] = p[n] + 1
  } else {
    p[n] = 1
  }
  return p
}, {});
```

- As a result you receive an object which counts the appearance of every value in the array
- Then you have the `return` statement which will return the first key of `counts` which has an odd value
- It does this by first creating an Array of the keys of `counts` with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- It then iterates over those keys and checks, whether the [modulo division](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Math#Arithmetic_operators) by 2 (`% 2`) of the value corresponding to every key is a truthy value (in this case not zero) and then return that key.
- It will always return the first key with that property
- At the end this found value is converted to a number with the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)
- If no value was found, undefined is returned

Comment: Elaborate and understandable! Thank you!

Comment: If you think this answers your question, please accept it as the correct answer to your question (checkmark left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

2 methods are used are used here that you need to understand.

1. reduce : read about it here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
2. find read about it here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

the below statement makes a map of a number vs its occurence

`let counts = A.reduce((p, n) => (p[n] = ++p[n] || 1, p), {})`

and then the second statement searches the map for an element which occurs odd number of times and if no such element it found it returns undefined

`return +Object.keys(counts).find(k => counts[k] % 2) || undefined`